# Maven unpack dependencies from Ant plugin mojo

Tags: maven, ant, maven-plugin

I have a Maven ant plugin that bundles up a library of Ant tasks. One of them has a lot of CI tasks.

I have the plugin working and can hit the task by running

```
mvn -U ci:options
```

This brings up a menu for the different operations.

The issue i'm having is that I need to resolve dependencies in the pom before the task is executed.

From reading up I would have thought that I could add

```
<execution>
    <goal>dependency:unpack-dependencies</goal>
</execution>
```

To the pluginMetaData xml file that defines the mojo, though this doesn't seem to do anything

**ci.mojos.xml**

```
<pluginMetadata xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/plugin-metadata-1.0.0.xsd">
<mojos>
    <mojo>
        <!-- target name to call in ant script -->
        <call>run</call>
        <!-- mojo goal name -->
        <goal>options</goal>
        <execution>
            <goal>dependency:unpack-dependencies</goal>
        </execution>
        <parameters>
            <parameter>
                <name>artifactId</name> 
                <property>artifactId</property> 
                <required>true</required> 
                <readonly>true</readonly>
                <type>java.lang.String</type>
                <defaultValue>${project.artifactId}</defaultValue>
                <description>Project Artifact Id</description>
            </parameter>
  ....
```

**ci.build.xml**

```
    <property name="project.home" location="."/>
    <property name="target.dir"       value="${project.home}/target"/>
    <property name="build.dir"        value="${target.dir}/build"/>
    <property name="dependency.dir"   value="${target.dir}/dependency"/>

    <!-- Add contrib to the classpath -->
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>

    <!-- Include ant utils from the shared resource -->
    <include file="${dependency.dir}/shared_ant/build.xml"/>

    <!-- Continuous Integration Options -->
    <target name="run" description="Continuous Integration Options">        
          <ci.options/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

James

Comment: Found https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MPLUGIN-239?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel which claims its fixed though don't think its released. Could explain it

Comment: Not a rhetorical question: would `requiresDependencyResolution` or `requiresDependencyCollection` be of any help to you in delegating the `unpack-dependencies` to Maven?

Comment: Hi, I tried that and it does work though I was originally running this outside of a phase. If I ran mvn compile ci:options then it does download the dependencies... I have had a re-think about this and experimenting with a different solution. Will post details when I have it working. Thanks for your time

Comment: I solved the initial include issue by using a java resource instead of include since all the ant scripts were on the classpath. All good though the ant macros are still reliant on dependencies. I have all this working if I add the dependencies to the project pom. I ideally want to have the dependencies detailed inside the plugin pom. Though I can't find a way to unpack them. The pluginMetaData fix allows goals to be triggered prior to running the main plugin goal though this seems to be local to the plugin. dependency:unpack-dependencies is from an external plugin so doesn't work.

Comment: The way in which dependencies of the plugin should not be essentially different between being defined in the plugin's POM or where the plugin is used.